How to Calculate Effective Memory Access Time with Multi-Level TLBs?
I’m working on a problem involving the calculation of effective memory-access time (EMAT) for a system with multi-level TLBs, and I want to confirm if my understanding is correct. Here’s the problem setup:

Problem Details:

Memory and TLB Parameters:

Memory access time (Δt_mem): 100 ns
TLB miss penalty: On a TLB miss, 4 additional memory accesses are required.
TLB access times:
Δt_TLB, L1-D = 1 ns
Δt_TLB, L2 = 5 ns


TLB hit rates:
ρ_TLB, L1-D = 30%
ρ_TLB, L2 = 98%




Behavior:

If an L1-D TLB hit occurs, the memory-access time includes just Δt_TLB, L1-D.
If the L1-D TLB misses but the L2 TLB hits, it adds Δt_TLB, L2.
If both TLB levels miss, it requires 4 additional memory accesses.




My Attempt:
I’ve tried breaking this into three cases:

Case 1: L1-D TLB Hit (30%):
Time = Δt_TLB, L1-D = 1 ns


Case 2: L1-D Miss, L2 TLB Hit (70% × 98%):
Time = Δt_TLB, L1-D + Δt_TLB, L2 = 1 ns + 5 ns = 6 ns


Case 3: Both L1-D and L2 TLB Miss (70% × 2%):
Time = Δt_TLB, L1-D + Δt_TLB, L2 + 4 × Δt_mem
Time = 1 ns + 5 ns + 4 × 100 ns = 406 ns



Finally, I believe the overall EMAT is the weighted sum of these cases based on their probabilities, but I’m unsure if I’m combining them correctly.

My Question:

Am I correctly handling the probabilities and adding the times for each case?
Is there a better way to approach this calculation?

I’d appreciate any clarification or suggestions to ensure my understanding is correct.
Thanks!

Your approach is fine.
Instead of three seperate cases you could also use this, which is not better but just another way of doing it:
EMAT = (L1 hit rate × L1 time) + 
   (L1 miss rate × L2 hit rate × L2 time) + 
   (L1 miss rate × L2 miss rate × full miss penalty)

